# QVTKWidget not showing colors on many faces when showing OBJ with mtl

Tags: 3d, vtk, qvtkwidget

My objective is to display OBJ files into QWidget. The code I have used to work previously.

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJImporter> importer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJImporter>::New();
    importer->SetFileName(graphics_path_balanced.toStdString().c_str());
    importer->SetFileNameMTL(graphics_path_balanced.append(".mtl").toStdString().c_str());
    importer->Read();
    importer->GetRenderer()->SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION >= 7 && VTK_MINOR_VERSION > 1
    importer->GetRenderer()->UseFXAAOn();
#endif
    vtkActorCollection* actors_collection = importer->GetRenderer()->GetActors();
    actors_collection->InitTraversal();
    while(vtkActor* actor = actors_collection->GetNextActor()) {
        actor->GetProperty()->SetOpacity(0.5);
    }
    importer->GetRenderWindow()->LineSmoothingOn();
    importer->GetRenderWindow()->PointSmoothingOn();
    importer->GetRenderWindow()->PolygonSmoothingOn();
    _visualization_balanced_viewer->SetRenderWindow(importer->GetRenderWindow());
```

[image]

The cuboids are not transparent. They are all solid blocks. Most of the faces loose its color and become transparent. However it used to show correctly before. Even if I turn off the opacity there is no difference.

It is an old code. However it seems that it was written with VTK 7.1 with Qt 5. It used to work in Mac as well as Arch Linux. But now it does not work in either of these OSs.

Comment: please specify your configuration (VTK version, how you get this  VTK, OS, Qt version ...)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Updated.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem in your case but the obj importer has changed between 7.1 and 8. You may want to look at this example : https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/IO/OBJImporter/